# JsonPath find all keys containing certain string?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have this `JSON`:

```
{
    "find-this": "sample1",
    "test": {
        "find-this": "sample2",
        "test": [
            {
                "find-this": "sample3",
                "test": "sample"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Using `JsonPath`, I want to get all elements that contain `this` in the `key`.

So the expected result is:

```json
[
  "find-this": "sample1",
  "find-this": "sample2",
  "find-this": "sample3"
]
```

So far I have only managed to filter by values and my research found this open issue [Regex support for Json key matching · Issue #348 · json-path/JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/348)

While regex matching would be nice, a simple `contains`, `starts with`, `ends with`, or `wildcard` search would also suffice but it does not seem to be supported yet.

Is there any way to make this currently work using `JsonPath`?

Comment: if all the keys are same you can use `$..['find-this']` to get the output as `["sample1","sample2","sample3"]`. Try here [JSONPath Online Evaluator](https://jsonpath.com/)

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar is there any way to do this with a partial string match?

Comment: Currently no support on keys. you need to write your own code